# how to set a key to a value of array - php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to set a key to parent value of my array.

my output is a parent value and a array ;

```
"parent":{

'A'=>value,

'B'=>value

}
```

output (To read output copy/paste into http://json.parser.online.fr/):

```
{"7916":{"id":"1168","GoodMainCode":"7916","title":"\u0632\u064a\u0631\u062f\u0633\u062a\u064a \u0637\u0644\u0642\u064a CLIP BOARD","author":" ","publisher":"\u0641\u0642\u064a\u0647\u064a \u0645\u0647\u0631","translator":" ","price":"20625","isbn":" ","amount":"0","year_of_publish":"0","period_print":"0"},"7989":{"id":"16827","GoodMainCode":"7989","title":"\u064a\u062f\u0643 \u0627\u062a\u0648\u062f5\u0645\u064a\u0644 \u0643\u0648\u0647 \u0646\u0648\u0631B6","author":" ","publisher":"","translator":" ","price":"108025","isbn":" ","amount":61,"year_of_publish":"0","period_print":"0"},"8350":{"id":"1225","GoodMainCode":"8350","title":"\u064a\u062f\u0643 \u0627\u062a\u0648\u062f\u0637\u0631\u0627\u062d\u064a2\u0645\u064a\u0644JBN","author":" ","publisher":"","translator":" ","price":"3375","isbn":" ","amount":"0","year_of_publish":"0","period_print":"0"}}
```

now, I want to set a key to 7916,7989,8350 . like :

```
"mykey"=>"parent":{

'A'=>value,
'B'=>value

}
```

how can I do that?

my function :

```
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

        $arr = array(
            'id'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['row1']),
            'GoodMainCode'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['GoodMainCode']),
            'title'=> persian_sql_to_php($row['GoodName']),
            'author'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['moalef']),
            'publisher'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Nasher']),
            'translator'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Motarjem']),
            'price'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['SellPrice1']),
            'isbn'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['ISBN']),
            'amount'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Amount']),
            'year_of_publish'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['SaleChap']),
            'period_print'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['NobateChap'])
        );


        array_push($mjson,$arr);

    }



  foreach($mjson as $v){

      if(!isset($result[$v['GoodMainCode']])){
          $result[$v['GoodMainCode']] = $v;
      }
      else
          $result[$v['GoodMainCode']]['amount'] += $v['amount'];
  }
```

Comment: based on your exact json data only, put your expected output. then only clarification and solution will made. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a generic push operation, which lets php figure out what the key should be. You need to explicitly set the key:

```
while($row = ...) {
   $arr[$row['row1']] = $row;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^---id value from database
}
```

As long as that `row1` value is the primary key for the record you're fetching, you'll end up with an array entry for every row. If `row` ISN'T unique, this would overwrite previous values with the new row.